# how to activate the root user and delete user 1 on console

Tags: root, accounts

First, I know this must be the a question asked so often, that you could not count it's duplicates. But all I found here has not solved my problem.

How to activate the root user after a fresh install and give him all privileges sp that I could delete the 1001 user after that.

This is to recreate a server environment created with ubuntu 14.04 where only a root user is active.

Answer (score 0):

To activate the root user run `sudo passwd` in terminal. Enter your sudo password to proceed. You will then be prompted for a new Unix password.

Answer (score 0):

1. goto "system settings" > User Accounts
2. click "unlock" and provide root password
3. create an user with "Account Type = administrative"  and set suitable password
4. delete the unused account you want.

Comment: sorry there is no distribution installed I need these instructions for console

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Then Try

$sudo su [ENTER] //IT WILL PROMPT FOR PASSWORD GIVE THE ROOT PASSWORD

TO CREATE NEW USER AND SET PASSWORD FOR ACTIVATE NEW USER

$ usradd username

$ passwd username

TO CHANGE ROOT PASSWORD

$sudo su [ENTER] //IT WILL PROMPT FOR PASSWORD GIVE THE ROOT PASSWORD

$passwd //IT WILL PROMPT FOR OLD PASSWORD IF YOU PROVIDE IT CORRECTLY THEN IT WILL PROMPT FOR NEW PASSWORD